# Not able to record script with Kerberos Authentication

Tags: jmeter, kerberos

When I'm trying to do load testing I've received an error related to Kerberos authentication:

```
jmeter.protocol.http.control.KerberosManager: Could not log in user ${AUTH_LOGIN} javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: kerberos.example.com
at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Unknown Source)
```

I've added the following properties to system properties but it doesn't work

```
java.security.krb5.conf=krb5.conf
java.security.auth.login.config=jaas.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding these 2 lines to *system.properties* file you need to:

1. Restart JMeter to pick the properties up
2. Perform [Kerberos Realm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/framework/GC32-0803-00/en_US/HTML/plan20.htm) configuration by providing your [KDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/secauthn/key-distribution-center) and [Admin Server](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_smart_cards/configuring_a_kerberos_5_server). You might also need to provide your domain controller IP address. Sample configuration would be something like:

   ```
   [libdefaults]
   default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM

   [realms]
   EXAMPLE.COM = {
           kdc = 10.20.30.40
           admin_server = 10.2.30.40
   }

   [domain_realm]
   10.20.30.40= EXAMPLE.COM
   .10.20.30.40= EXAMPLE.COM
   ```

   Replace `EXAMPLE.COM` with your fully qualified domain name and `10.20.30.40` with the IP address of your primary domain controller. The actual configuration might be different so contact your network administrator and/or application developers to get exact details.

More information:

- [Explain like I’m 5: Kerberos](http://www.roguelynn.com/words/explain-like-im-5-kerberos/)
- [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)

Comment: TCurrently, I've received the next error 'jmeter.protocol.http.control.KerberosManager: Could not log in user ${AUTH_LOGIN} javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Receive timed out
'